# Is this definition of the gradient using the exterior derivative consistent with calculus 1?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, differential-forms, differential

I'm trying to get a better grasp on what the exterior derivative means on my own and I'm trying to connect the language of forms to my pre-existing knowledge. I came along the following formula for the gradient on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative):
$$\text{grad}f=\nabla f=(df)^\sharp$$
where $d$ is the exterior derivative and $^\sharp$ is a musical isomorphism. Since $(\omega_ie^i)^\sharp=\omega^ie_i$ this gives the following definition in component form
$$\nabla f=e_i\partial^if=(\partial^if)\frac{\partial}{\partial  x^i}.$$
From my calculus classes I remember the gradient being defined as a vector which is consistent with this formula. But what confuses me is that the vector component have *raised indices*. In Cartesian coordinates you wouldn't notice this but in polar coordinates, or any other coordinates for that matter, you would notice a difference. But again when I recall my calculus classes I remember always calculating the ordinary partial derivatives which correspond to lower indices $\partial_i f$. So is this definition consistent with elementary calculus intuition? So my elementary calculus definition would perhaps be $(\partial_i f)e_i$ even though I know that wouldn't make sense.

Comment: In calculus classes — and, indeed, in much of mathematics — no one writes coordinates with raised indices or pays attention to covariance or contravariance.

Comment: @TedShifrin That makes sense but shouldn't it make a difference in non-cartesian coordinates?

Comment: Where you put your indices is irrelevant. The upper-lower convention is there only to help guide you with the Einstein summation convention. But, yes, without an orthonormal coordinate system, the correspondence between differential forms and vector fields is more complicated, and this is the underlying reason formulas for the gradient change. It's the differential form $df$ is that is well-defined.

Comment: Normally you would use the *reciprocal basis* for the gradient. This the unique **vector** basis $r^i$ such that $r^i\cdot e_j = \delta^i_j$ where $\cdot$ is the metric. We use raised indices here for a very good reason: $r^i = (e^i)^\sharp$. So then $\nabla f = r^i\partial_if$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question in the title is "yes," and here's why.

As the [Wikipedia article on the musical isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism) explains, the so-called "musical isomorphism" is equivalent to raising and lowering indices  (sometimes called "index juggling") in component form. The process of raising and lowering indices is allowed due to the metric ($g_{ij}$) and its inverse ($g^{ij}$) imposed on the manifold. Specifically, a vector $\vec X=X^i\vec e_i$ is related to the $1$-form $\tilde X=X_i\tilde\omega^i$ by the equation $X^i=g^{ij}X_j$ under the standard coordinate bases $\vec e_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial q^i}$ and $\tilde\omega^i={\bf d} q^i$ for some set of coordinates $q^i$ if the usual $1$-form and metric requirements are imposed (viz. ${\bf d}q^i(\frac{\partial}{\partial q^j})=\delta^{i}_{\ \ j}$ and $g^{ik}g_{kj}=\delta^i_{\ \ j}$).

Using this relationship, ${\bf d}f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial q^i}{\bf d}q^i$ is related to $\vec\nabla f=(\partial^if)\frac{\partial}{\partial q^i}=(g^{ij}\frac{\partial f}{\partial q^j})\frac{\partial}{\partial q^i} $ through an obvious application of index juggling (which, remember, is the same as the musical isomorphism).

And you are correct that the raised index (which is hiding that inverse metric tensor) is important in other coordinate systems. Look at the [definition of the gradient in other coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates) and you will notice that additional factors are present that resemble the elements of the inverse metric. If you look carefully, they appear (at least for cylindrical and spherical coordinates) to be the square root of those elements. The reason for this is that the definitions given on that Wikipedia page use normalized unit vectors instead of the standard basis of partial derivatives. The normalization factor is exactly the square root of those terms, so the unit vectors are actually hiding a portion of the inverse metric's contribution to the final answer.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I guess the main take away for me is that I have used 'raised indices' to compute the gradient all these years without knowing it!